# Trying to flash an STM32F3 Discovery board using OpenOCD: `no flash bank found`

Tags: stm32, jtag, openocd

I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/antoinealb/rust-demo-cortex-m4) and tried to flash my STM32F3 DIscovery board using `make flash`. The relevant rule is this:

```
flash: main.axf
    openocd -f oocd.cfg -c "program main.axf verify reset" -c "shutdown"
```

oocd.cfg:

```
telnet_port 4444
gdb_port 3333

source [find board/stm32f3discovery.cfg]
```

`make flash` then gives me the following output:

```
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
none separate
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v21 API v2 SWIM v0 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 2.883108
Info : stm32f3x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0800234c msp: 0x2000a000
adapter speed: 8000 kHz
** Programming Started **
auto erase enabled
Info : device id = 0x10036422
Info : flash size = 256kbytes
Warn : no flash bank found for address 0
Warn : no flash bank found for address 704
wrote 0 bytes from file main.axf in 0.001628s (0.000 KiB/s)
** Programming Finished **
```

The `program` command shows me that `no flash bank found` and no data was written. Naturally, the `verify` command fails.

I built OpenOCD from the 0.9 tag. I installed `libusb-1.0-0-dev` using aptitude, which was necessary for ST-Link support.

What is wrong in my configuration, or is there an alternative to OpenOCD that I could try for this task?

Comment: Hello it look like you have wrong defined FLASH address, it flashing from address `0`, and not from `0x08000000` where FLASH in STM32F3 is.

I have short look into github repository and the problem seems in linker script, in file `LM4F.ld` is defined FLASH address at `0x00000000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong defined FLASH address. It is flashing from address `0`, and not from `0x08000000` where FLASH in STM32F3 is.

I had a short look into the GitHub repository and the problem seems to be in the linker script. In file `LM4F.ld` the FLASH address is defined at `0x00000000`.

Comment: Thanks, I use for flashing STM this app: https://github.com/pavelrevak/pystlink although there is no support for GDB or iHex files, but it has very simple command line interface and don't need any special configuration files.